# How to define sort(List,Sorted) in Prolog

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

How to define the predicate `sort(List,Sorted)` in Prolog?
E.g., `sort([3,2,4],[2,3,4])` returns true.
I know there is a built-in predicate of this, but I want to know how to define it.

Comment: I'm willing to bet you can find more answers to this in books and with a simple google search than anyone could ever provide you. [Case in point...](http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/sorting.html) took me less than 20 seconds to find

Comment: I didn't find one. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: @vmg note that all algorithms shown there use arithmetic comparisons throughout and will sort arithmetic expressions (or numbers). You need at least to change the comparison predicates if you want to sort arbitrary terms.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but a few suggestions that are too long for a comment.

You probably realize that, but still, keep in mind that defining your sort is purely an exercise with the purpose of learning Prolog syntax. You should always use the library `sort` if you actually need to sort stuff.

Then,  "... but I want to know how to define it": What does that mean? Does it mean that you have chosen a sorting algorithm, but you are not sure about how to implement it in Prolog? Or that you have trouble choosing one of several algorithms? Or that you don't know what sorting algorithms exist?

And a suggestion: when choosing a sorting algorithm, prefer one that is meant to be used with singly linked lists. Prolog lists are quite similar to singly linked lists.

And another suggestion: look at existing code (as one commenter nicely pointed out), and also look at the library code of one of the free Prolog implementations. For example, [here is the full code of a sort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/sort.pl?show=src#predsort/3) available from SWI-Prolog. It is easy to find, if you just spend a few minutes searching instead of immediately asking for help.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I did by my own without looking other staff.